# how can I test a parser generated by antlr v4?

Tags: java, junit, antlr

Is there a way that I can test a parser generated by antlr v4 using junit? Any examples that I can borrow? Should I be using gunit from v3 instead? Not sure if that is available anymore.

Comment: Give it something to parse, check if the output is the one you expect? What's the concrete problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test that all the available correct samples you can lay your hands on are parsed successfully, and that as many error cases you can reasonably and economically find or create produce parsing errors. The former is a lot more important than the latter. Yu oh also he'd t check that the obvious things like operator precedence and if/else shift-reduce conflicts are handled correctly, via testing of whatever the output is.